# Web-scraping data that's not a typical table - python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to find a way to pull data from a rotogrinders page, not in a typical table form. I'm new, and previously did a very basic:

```
    url = 'site.com' 
    html = requests.get(url).content
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)
    temp_df = df_list[-1]
```

which has been sufficent...but this is different.

if you look at https://rotogrinders.com/lineups/nfl?week=1&site=fanduel, I'd like to get the list of players of each team, in the order they're listed (top to bottom). From there I'll be able to do a depth chart by team, but I need to get that list of players and positions. Each team is in a separate column and then grouped by the two teams that are playing each other. I'd only need the Name and position, but if the other info was there, that would be fine.

Essentially, this is what I'd like the output to be:

```
Alex Smith        QB $7.2K 31.0
Patrick Mahomes   QB 0
Kareem Hunt       RB $7.8K 43.1
Charcandrick West RB $5.2K 9.0
C.J. Spiller      RB $4.5K 0
Tyreek Hill       WR $7.2K 23.3
Chris Conley      WR $4.9K 5.3
Albert Wilson     WR $4.9K 6.2
De'Anthony Thomas WR $4.5K 0.7
Demarcus Robinson WR $4.5K 0
Travis Kelce      TE $6.7K 6.9
Demetrius Harris  TE $4.5K 8.5
Cairo Santos       K $4.6K 6.0
Tom Brady         QB $9.2K 10.7
Jimmy Garoppolo   QB $6K 0
Mike Gillislee    RB $6.7K 22.5
James White       RB $5.7K 8.3
Dion Lewis        RB $5.1K 0.9
Brandin Cooks     WR $7.9K 10.3
Chris Hogan       WR $6.2K 3.0
Danny Amendola    WR $6.1K 13.0
Malcolm Mitchell  WR $4.9K 0
Phillip Dorsett   WR $5K 0.0
Rob Gronkowski    TE $8.1K 4.3
Dwayne Allen      TE $4.9K 0.0
Stephen Gostkowski K $5.1K 9.0
...               ... .....
```

followed by the rest of the teams.

Edit: So here's what I'm working from.

```
url = 'https://rotogrinders.com/lineups/nfl?week=1&site=fanduel'
page = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
name_box = soup.find('li', attrs={'class': 'player'})
name = name_box.text.strip()
```

and here's what I'm getting. I'm trying to figure out how to get from what I currently have (which is just the first player, with all that white space), into the output I;ve shown above.

here's my output:

```
print (name)
Alex Smith




                                        QB



                                    $7.2K

31.0
```

Comment: Try work with beautifulsoup.

Comment: Yes. I've been working with beautifulsoup. Just having a hard time with it. I've got the basic, now just trying to expand on it. 

Look above, I've added to the question where I'm at with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bs4
import requests as re
import pandas as pd


alpha  = re.get('https://rotogrinders.com/lineups/nfl?week=1&site=fanduel')

beta = bs4.BeautifulSoup(alpha.text,'lxml')

gama = beta.findAll('a',{'class':'player-popup'})
lister = [a.text for a in gama]

positions = beta.findAll('span',{'class':'position'})
positionslist=[span.text for span in positions]

salaries = beta.findAll('span',{'class':"salary"})
salarieslist = [span.text for span in salaries]

points = beta.findAll('span',{'class':"fpts actual"})
pointslist = [span.text for span in points]



target = pd.DataFrame(

{

'player name':lister
,'positions':positionslist
,'salaries':salarieslist
,'points':pointslist
})
```